# RxJava subscription does not unsubscribe correctly

Tags: model-view-controller, rx-java, observable

I have an MVC application in which I have to update the view with the current value of a stream.
In the model I have this method:

```
public Observable<Integer> getStreamInstance(){
    if(stream == null){
        this.stream = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) -> {
            new HeartbeatStream(frequence,subscriber).start();
        }); 
    }

    return stream;
}
```

which I use in the controller to get the stream. Then, in the controller I have these two methods:

```
public void start(){
    this.sb = stream.subscribe((Integer v) -> {
        view.updateCurrValue(v);
    });
}

public void stop(){
    this.sb.unsubscribe();      
}
```

With the start method I simply update a label in the view with the current value.
This works fine until I try to stop the updating with the unsubscribing; infact, when I press the button "stop" in the view, the label keeps updating with the current value and, if I press "start" again, the label shows the values from two different streams, the one that I first created with the first "start" and the second that seems has been created with the second pressing of "start". 
Where am I wrong?

EDIT:

```
public class HeartbeatStream extends Thread{

private Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber;
private int frequence;
private HeartbeatSensor sensor;

public HeartbeatStream(int freq, Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber){
    this.frequence = freq;
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
    sensor = new HeartbeatSensor();
}

public void run(){

    while(true){        
        try {
            subscriber.onNext(sensor.getCurrentValue());
            Thread.sleep(frequence);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }


}
```

This is the HeartbeatStream class. HeartbeatSensor is a class that periodically generates a value that simulates the heartbeat frequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable by design unsubscribe your observer once that all items are emitted and onComplete callback is invoked.

Look this example https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableSubscription.java

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you tried to periodically signal some event that triggers the screen update. There is an operator for that:

```
Observable<Long> timer = Observable.interval(period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
     AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

SerialSubscription serial = new SerialSubscription();

public void start() {
    serial.set(timer.subscribe(v -> view.updateCurrValue(v)));
}

public void stop() {
    serial.set(Subscriptions.unsubscribed());
}

public void onDestroy() {
    serial.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not handling the `unsubscribe` - although I can't see what's going on in your `HeartbeatStream` class.

If you're creating an `Observable` with `Observable.create` then you need to handle unsubscribing explicitly with `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()`.

Where possible use some of the utility methods to create an Observable - they handle this all for you eg `Observable.just()` or `Observable.from()`.

If this doesn't help, please post your HeartbeatStream class.

See the the docs for more details:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators

Comment: I've added the  heartbeatStream class